R package build workflow on Github Actions - prevent compiling dependencies from source?
My CI Github Actions build workflow for an R package is failing for a single release (win 3.6.3) because (as far as I can tell) it is attempting to build a dependency from source. Is there a flag I can set in the yaml that tells it to only use compiled versions of dependencies?

Thanks.
Logs can be seen here.
And here is the workflow.
# Workflow derived from https://github.com/r-lib/actions/tree/v2/examples
# Need help debugging build failures? Start at https://github.com/r-lib/actions#where-to-find-help
on:
  push:
    branches: [main, master, develop]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main, master, develop]

name: R-CMD-check

jobs:
  R-CMD-check:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.config.os }}

    name: ${{ matrix.config.os }} (${{ matrix.config.r }})

    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        config:
          - {os: macos-latest,   r: 'release'}
          - {os: macOS-latest,   r: 'devel'}
          - {os: macOS-latest,   r: 'oldrel-1'}
          - {os: macOS-latest,   r: '3.6.3'}
          - {os: macOS-latest,   r: '4.1.1'}
          - {os: macOS-latest,   r: '4.2.2'}
          - {os: windows-latest, r: 'release'}
          - {os: windows-latest, r: 'devel'}
          - {os: windows-latest, r: 'oldrel-1'}
          - {os: windows-latest, r: '3.6.3'}
          - {os: ubuntu-latest,  r: 'release'}
          - {os: ubuntu-latest,  r: 'devel', http-user-agent: 'release'}
          - {os: ubuntu-latest,  r: 'oldrel-1'}
          - {os: ubuntu-20.04,   r: 'release', rspm: "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/latest"}
          - {os: ubuntu-20.04,   r: 'devel', rspm: "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/latest", http-user-agent: "R/4.1.0 (ubuntu-20.04) R (4.1.0 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu x86_64 linux-gnu) on GitHub Actions" }


    env:
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      R_KEEP_PKG_SOURCE: yes

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-pandoc@v2

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v2
        with:
          r-version: ${{ matrix.config.r }}
          http-user-agent: ${{ matrix.config.http-user-agent }}
          use-public-rspm: true

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v2
        with:
          extra-packages: any::rcmdcheck
          needs: check

      - uses: r-lib/actions/check-r-package@v2
        with:
          upload-snapshots: true

